# Colon breaks the variable subsitution

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, escape-characters, variable-substitution

I am trying to lookup some C functions so that I could debug while using strace. So I setup a bash function to look it up in firefox (or links), but the substitution falls apart with `:` and escaping does not work, at least not in a simple way.

#### Working

```
ff() {
    firefox "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%*"
}
```

#### Not working

```
cr() {
    firefox "codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:%*"
}
```

firefox gets `:` parsed in as input, but also $* gets parse in as literal characters.

#### Tried:

```
1. Escaping : % *
2. Enclosing ${%*}
3. Changing " '
4. EnvVariable COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}
```

**Edit:** My question is flawed. My working code had `$*` all along. I wish to delete my question, but I leave it for reference to people who might be encouraged to write answers and improve questions on similar problem.

Comment: Not an answer for you, but [surfraw](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/) does exactly this...

Comment: Glad it helped...

Comment: I also recommend `man 2 ...` for a quick system call look up.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `%*` to `$*` fixed the problem.

Comment: If you read your question well, you'll notice that you wrote `$*` in the question and `%*` in the code. :)